# Googlemap not showing inside a coordinatelayout in child activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-coordinatorlayout

In my current project I have BaseActivity child activity feature.

Base xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".Activity.BaseActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBody"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/toolbaar_layout"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

So all the child activities are added to this llbody layout and viewed as required.

Now in one of my activity I need to show a map.

If I create a mapfragment xml as simple as

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".Activity.MapsActivity"/>
```

Its showing map as usual. but I plan to do a bit of design and stuff so i need floatingbutton, so I need to have a coordinatelayout. So I created the xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Activity.BaseActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But now the problem arises that is

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

mapfragment is null, its not able to find the mapfragment.

Any hint what might be going wrong? Any clues..

Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting `MapFragment` to `SupportMapFragment` which may cause issue. Use `SupportMapFragment` with `AppCompat` Library.

Change the fragment in xml as.

```
  <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used your same xml file in java code i changed like this.It is working for me

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Add api key in manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="write_your_api_key_here" />
```